# Avoid self=this in JavaScript type functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

How can I avoid doing `const self = this` in JavaScript/Node.js in each type function?

```
function Server(config) {
    const self = this;
    this.config = config;

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(self.config);
    }, 2000);
}

Server.prototype.foo = function() {
    const self = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(self.config);
    }, 4000);
};

module.exports = Server;
```

It is very error prone *(do I use `this` or `self`)* because you have to look at your scope. Not to mention it feels unnecessary to declare extra variables.

Comment: It's only error prone if you don't use `self` for every subsequent operation

Comment: `setTimeout` accepts additional args that can be passed on to the callback if you prefer, so `setTimeout(function(self) { console.log(self.config) }, this)` You'll need to fix this in old versions of FF and IE though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set the this keyword to the provided value:

```
Server.prototype.listen = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(this.config);
  }.bind(this));
};
```

Or alternatively in an ES2015 ready environment you use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which have a lexical this value:

```
Server.prototype.listen = function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.config);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have ES6 (I see usage of `const`), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) should be available. More information can be found in [this section of the same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this).

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: @Justin Arrow function won't bind to `this`

Comment: Look at the document @Joseph the Dreamer has linked you to.  There is an example there.